# Vue 'computed property' is not invoked for input type date

Tags: vue.js

```js
  var myObject = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: { dateOfBirth: '2020-01-01', age: 0 },
            computed: {                               
                result: function () {
                    debugger                    
                    const systemDateYear = moment().year();     
                    const myDOB = new Date(this.dateOfBirth);
                    this.age = systemDateYear - myDOB.getFullYear();        
                }
            }
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
        <input type="date" v-model="dateOfBirth">
        <input type="number" v-model="age">           
    </div>
```

Not sure why the 'computed property' is not invoked here when I select the date from this date input type. But when I moved out the code (calculating age), it works. Below is when I moved out the code from the computed property.

```
const systemDateYear = moment().year();     

const myDOB = new Date(myObject.dateOfBirth);
myObject.age = systemDateYear - myDOB.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`age` should be defined as [Computed Property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and you need to add `return` statement in `function`:

```js
  var myObject = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: { dateOfBirth: '' },
            computed: {                               
                age: function () {
                    debugger                    
                    const systemDateYear = moment().year();     
                    const myDOB = new Date(this.dateOfBirth);
                    return systemDateYear - myDOB.getFullYear();        
                }
            }
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
        <input type="date" v-model="dateOfBirth">
        <input type="number" v-model="age">           
    </div>
```

Comment: It works. One more thing, how do I set default value for date to make my age empty until user select it?

Comment: @Steve I updated answer: `data: { dateOfBirth: '' }`